# Cómo podria incluir, dentro del jar de mi programa java, el navegador chromeForTesting, sobre el que se va a realizar una bateria de pruebas

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-ng

Actualmente me encuentro desarrollando un software de test automatizado con Selenum y TestNG, dicho software quiero que sea portable, ya tengo todo lo necesario dentro del jar, dependencias, driver, fichero xml, donde se definen los test, solo me falta agregar un navegador estable, que no se auto actualice, pero a la hora de agregar como recurso del jar, el navegador, "Chrome for Testing" y agregar su binario a las opciones del driver, me corre perfecto con maven mientras que si ejecuto el programa desde el jar me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Error en la configuración: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at file: <ruta del jar>!/chrome/chrome-win64/chrome.exe
```

Y la verdad no se como solucionarlo, porque el fichero .exe existe y se genera y es dentro de esa ruta..... mientras que el driver,al cual accedo con el mismo método si que me lo encuntra....
He probado de todo, permisos, crear ficheros temporales y pasar dicha ruta al .setBinary y nada.

Muchas gracias por su atención y pido perdón de antemanos si en mi explicación hay algún fallo de conceptos o de conocimiento, acabo de empezar en esto de la programación. GRACIAS!!!!!